# Crystal XI Conditional Print of Sections in Page Header

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working with a Crystal XI Report. I have the layout of the report like below....

Page Header a: Shows Property Number

Page Header b: Shows Property Summary

Page Header c: Shows Park Management

Page Header d: Shows Land Information

Page Header e: Shows Lease Information

Page Header f: Shows column labels for my details section. The columns are...

Land ID, Address, Section .....etc.

Then there is the details section which is a sub report that shows the bulk of the report

Land ID, Address, Section etc.

e.g.

### Property: 0001

Property Summary: Blah blah blah

Park Mangement Info: Blah Blah Blah

Land Info: Blah Blah Blah

Lease Info: Blah Blah Blah

LandID Address Section

0001   4/6abc  section1

0002   4/7abc  section1

0003   4/8abc  section1

...
...
...

### etc etc.

I want the report to start on new page for every property.
To do this I have 'New page after' ticked on my details section. 
Works like a dream...Except the user came with this...

Each time I print a new page, the page header b, c, d, and e print too. They don't want this to happen. So now, on the first property page, I want all the page headers but for every subsequent page, I want to print only the page header a which is the property number and the page header f which is the column labels. How do I do this.

On header b,c,d,e, I wish to put an expression under suppress (no drill down) such that one every subsequent print of the same property number, the b,c,d,e don't print.

Answer (score 0):

Did this eventually this morning.
Based it on tip off from Mahesh Chand from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com

1
I defined my contents in b, c, d, e as detail sections rather than page headers.

2
In my sub report, I created a group on the property_no key field (although the value remains the same for the sub report). Ticked the flag for printing the group header on page break.

3
I pushed the column labels in section f into this sub report group header.

Worked beautifully.